# write systemd script for influxdb for a yocto build

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, systemd, influxdb

I have an application where I wish to have **InfluxDB** on a [PHYTEC Mira board](http://www.phytec.eu/product/single-board-computer/phyboard-mira/). I have found the a `meta` layer for the same and on initial build I was successful to have it compiled on board.

Upon Boot:

```
 $influxd
```

needs to be started first and then subsequently:

```
$ influx
```

to run the shell influxDB

I however want to include a `influxd.service` **systemd** script

```
[Unit]
Description=InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
Documentation=https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
After=network.target

[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/influxdb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/influxd $INFLUXD_OPTS
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'while ! influx -execute exit >& /dev/null;
do sleep 0.1;done'
KillMode=control-group
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=influxd.service
```

but within the yocto structure I do not know where to place it in order to make is available for all subsequent builds.

According to the [board's BSP Manual, section CAN Bus](http://www.phytec.de/documents/l-814e-3-imx6-bsp-manual/) I placed the above mentioned `.service` script in

```
meta-yogurt/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-machine-units/
```

folder

I made a new image and on booting the board I tried:

```
  systemctl start influxd.service
```

but there does not exist such a script. I tried looking into the `/lib/systemd/system/` folder on the board to see if the `influxd.service` file exists but it doesn't.

### Update

This is the current file structure:
where `meta-umg` is a custom-layer and within it is the `recipes-go/go/` as it is in the [`meta-influx` layer](https://github.com/C-X1/meta-influx)

```
../sources/meta-umg/
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-go
└── go
├── files
│   └── influxd.service
└── github.com-influxdata-influxdb_%.bbappend
```

The `github.com-influxdata-influxdb_%.bbappend` has the same content as @Nayfe mentioned.

Upon executing `bitbake -e github.com-influxdata-influxdb` I get the following error:

> No recipes available for:
>     /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-umg/recipes-go/go/github.com-influxdata-influxdb_%.bbappend

I guess the `%` is not valid since the recipe has no versions attached to it.

So I went ahead and changed the name of the `.bbappend` file to `github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bbappend` and

```
bitbake -e github.com-influxdata-influxdb | grep ^SYSTEMD_
```

provides

```
bitbake -e github.com-influxdata-influxdb | grep ^SYSTEMD_
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE="enable"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_github.com-influxdata-influxdb="influxd.service"
SYSTEMD_PACKAGES="github.com-influxdata-influxdb"
SYSTEMD_PACKAGES_class-native=""
SYSTEMD_PACKAGES_class-nativesdk=""
```

and

```
bitbake-layers show-appends | grep "github.com*"
Parsing recipes..done.
github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bb:
  /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky/../meta-umg/recipes-go/go/github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bbappend
```

When I create an image where my `local.conf` file has `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " github.com-influxdata-influxdb`

The SystemD script is available in the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.wants/` folder but the daemon `influxd` and `influx` shell commands are not installed on the board.

I suspect that removing the `%` sign overrides the complete installation recipe.

*update1*

`oe-pkg-utils list-pkg-files -p github.com-influxdata-influxdb` provides the following output when the layer is added and compiled using `bitbake github.com-influxdata-influxdb`

```
github.com-influxdata-influxdb:
    /lib/systemd/system/influxd.service
github.com-influxdata-influxdb-dbg:
github.com-influxdata-influxdb-dev:
```

Comment: Which version of Yocto do you use?

Comment: Maybe use this [meta-influx](https://github.com/kraj/meta-influx/tree/kraj/develop) fork? If you don't have influxd and influx binaries/scripts, you need to check with `bitbake -e github.com-influxdata-influxdb | grep ^FILES` and also check [oe-pkgdata-util](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#viewing-package-information-with-oe-pkgdata-util) tool to see where those are installed. You can also browse recipe build folder for files in image folder.

Comment: @Nayfe I was previously using the fork you mentioned but it didn't compile on my host and hence reverted back to the main repo. I will look into the version and the above mentioned checks.

Comment: @Nayfe Yocto kernel version `4.1.36-phy3` Kernel name `linux-mainline` and Bitbake version `1.30.0`

Comment: can you give the result of the following command `oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p github.com-influxdata-influxdb` ?

Comment: @Nayfe added the output from `oe-pkg-utils`

Comment: It means base recipe doesn't add any file to deploy folder. I think it is related to legacy `oe-meta-go` `go.bbclass` handling, I'm not sure how it works as it is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append influxd recipe and create a files folder with influxd.service in it.

**influxd_%.bbappend:**

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

inherit systemd

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "influxd.service"

SRC_URI += " \
            file://influxd.service \
           "

do_install_append () {
    # systemd
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/influxd.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
}
```

PS: i assume your influxd recipe name is influxd, if you are using `github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bb`, you'll need to create `github.com-influxdata-influxdb.bbappend`.

Comment: hi, so this goes in my `meta-influx` folder? or in the `.bbappend` file in the `meta-yogurt` folder?

Comment: You have to create your own layer, you can look [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-your-own-layer) for details. You can also modify original recipe from `meta-influx`, and then send a pull request to get your changes upstream.

Comment: The main repo is dead for a long time. Maybe i will create `meta-mytest` layer and then create `github.com-influxdata-influxbb.bbappend` to create your above mentioned file. Or should I do something other wise?

Comment: Nop, it's ok with bbappend

Comment: The question is will there be any issues in recognizing what actually is `github.com-influxdata-influxdb` in general for the Yocto build

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170098/discussion-between-shan-desai-and-nayfe).